# Excel how can I group by column A and calculate the average according to the value group by in column A

Tags: excel, average

[image]

I have tried to use =Ifaverage. but be honest I have no idea about Excel. I never worked with it. thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should do the trick:

```
=LET(a,A1:A6,b,B1:B6,c,UNIQUE(a),HSTACK(c,MAP(c,LAMBDA(z,AVERAGE(FILTER(b,a=z))))))
```

Result:

[image]

Or use `UNIQUE` (`=UNIQUE(A1:A6)` in `A10`) to get unique values and then use `AVERAGEIF`:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$6,A10,$B$1:$B$6)
```

[image]

Also instead of dragging down formula above, spill is possible with:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$6,A10#,$B$1:$B$6)
```

(if A10 contains formula `=UNIQUE(A1:A6)`, otherwise use `=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$6,UNIQUE(A1:A6),$B$1:$B$6)`   )