# Excel - Aggregating Data in One Column Based on Values in Another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, average

I am trying to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77645814/excel-how-can-i-group-by-column-a-and-calculate-the-average-according-to-the-val) to answer my question. I have data like this:

[image]

Columns A and B are my data. I want to aggregate the data in columns A and B for every integer value in A by averaging the values in column B. So for every value in A that starts with a 17 I want an average of the 4 corresponding values in B and so on.  Here is what I have tried. In column C I round column A down to the nearest integer.

In column D I use `=UNIQUE(C1:C11466)` to get only the unique values in C. Then in column E I am using `=AVERAGEIF($C$1:$C$11466,D1#,$B$1:$B$11466)` but you can see it isn't working. I'm reproducing the answer in the link (I think) but I'm not sure why it is not working.

I think there should be an easier way to do this but so far this method is the closest I've gotten. I would prefer to not use pivot tables unless there is no other way, I understand that may work also.

Comment: Values in E2 and down doesn't let formula to spill result. Empty whole column and then paste formula in E1. More on #SPILL! error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula here:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:B26,
     _ColA, INT(TAKE(_Data,,1)),
     _UniqColA, UNIQUE(_ColA),
     HSTACK(_UniqColA,BYROW(_UniqColA, LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(FILTER(TAKE(_Data,,-1),_ColA=x))))))
```

---

Also if applicable one can use `GROUPBY()`

```
=GROUPBY(INT(A1:A26),B1:B26,AVERAGE,,0)
```

---

Edit - Here is as per OP's comments:

> *No worries! Yes, so also average 4 more columns C, D, E, and F (not*
> *shown in my example) in their own new columns just like column B. I*
> *didn't ask this originally because I thought I could adapt the answer*
> *for the simple case to additional columns*

---

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data,A1:C26,
     _ColA, INT(TAKE(_Data,,1)),
     _OtherCols, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_ColA),
     _Avgs, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),COLUMNS(_OtherCols),LAMBDA(r,c,
            LET(x, FILTER(_OtherCols,_ColA=INDEX(_Uniq,r),0),
            AVERAGE(IFERROR(INDEX(x,,c),0))))),
     HSTACK(_Uniq,_Avgs))
```

---

And using `GROUPBY()`

```
=GROUPBY(INT(A1:A26),HSTACK(B1:C26),AVERAGE,,0)
```

---

The formula using `MAKEARRAY()` can be made bit shorter, I have added an additional `LET()` function within it to make it understandable.

---

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the first option. At the very bottom I get a 0 in one column and then a #DIV/0! in the next column. It can be ignored, but do you know why?

Comment: Yes please use `IFERROR()` --> `AVERAGE(IFERROR(FILTER(`

Comment: Ok, what if I have other columns similar to column B that I also want to average? I could copy the data next to column A and repeat the formula, but is there an easier way?

Comment: So that should be an another column of average ? sorry for the delay i wasn't not in front of the pc

Comment: No worries! Yes, so also average 4 more columns C, D, E, and F (not shown in my example) in their own new columns just like column B. I didn't ask this originally because I thought I could adapt the answer for the simple case to additional columns.

Comment: @Chris I will update the post, btw it will easy be if you are having a column of `UNIQUE()` and using the `AVERAGEIFS()` function --> `=AVERAGEIF($C$1:$C$11466,$D$1#,B$1:B$11466)` now drag right it will give for respective columns, note that for `Column C` --> `INT(A1:A11466)`

Comment: What is $D$1 referencing?

Comment: How do I expand it? I change A1:C26 for whatever my data range is, correct? In the 5th line, after `Uniq`, do I change that to the number of rows I have? Is there anything else that needs to change?

Comment: Yes, Change in first step `_Data` --> to any number of `Cols`

Comment: Thank you. I changed to six columns A2:F11467 (I have column headers), but I am only seeing three columns as a result, the unique rounded values from column A and the averaged values from column B and C.

Comment: @Chris see my latest update, I fotgot to update `Columns` --> `c` in `MAKEARRAY()`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again for all of the help!

Comment: @Chris just note the second `LET()` within `MAKEARRAY()` is not needed it is redundant, i have used only to make it step by step so you understand clearly, you can remove it, then it becomes. `MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),COLUMNS(_OtherCols),LAMBDA(r,c,
            AVERAGE(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(_OtherCols,_ColA=INDEX(_Uniq,r),0),,c),0)))))`